# How can i "externalize" material-ui from a react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

i am working on an react app creadted with the "create-react-app my-app --template cra-template-pwa-typescript" command.
Also i am using the material-ui package for the interface.
Now i want to use material-ui through an cdn. so i need to exclude this package via the "externals" config. I am using "react-app-rewired" to override the default config.

But i dont find a proper way to define the externals. found several examples,
for example:

```
externals = [
  //...other externals working fine
  /@material-ui\/.*/
]
```

or

```
externals = [
  "@material-ui/core",
  "@material-ui/icons",
  /@material-ui\/core\/.*/,
  /@material-ui\/icons\/.*/,
}
```

But when using this method i got an error while compiling

```
Failed to compile.

Failed to minify the code from this file:

        external "@material-ui/core":1
```

Also tried the solution described here:
https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/11777#issuecomment-452306347
Here i dont get an error, but the material-ui package didnt excluded and is still bundled.